# Using Stenciljs web component library with Svelte

Tags: svelte, web-component, stenciljs

I've been struggling to figure out how to use my StencilJS web component library with Svelte. Below is the best I can come up with. Which works, but I'm wondering if it's the "correct" way to do it.

```
<script>
    import {defineCustomElements} from "@oac/stencil-library/loader";
    defineCustomElements();
</script>

<my-component></my-component>
```

Based on the [JavaScript](https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript) docs that use the CDN, it seems I should be able to load them in a single file without calling the `defineCustomElements()` function.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ion-toggle></ion-toggle>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wonder if I can do something like this with an `npm` installed package imported into Svelte. Along the lines of `import '@oac/stencil-library'` or `import '@oac/stencil-library/dist/index.js'`, I can't seem to find an import path that works.

Also, is it possible to load in a single component? This may be a large library. We wouldn't want end users to load every component if we can help it.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple approaches work, though there are differences in when/how the code is executed.

You can add scripts to the head via [`<svelte:head>`](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#svelte-head):

```html
<svelte:head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic.js"></script>
</svelte:head>
```

This should also include the tag in server-side rendering, if you have that configured.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't know what this achieves. I'm trying to import my own library with ESM; just not sure I'm doing it right. Would there be an import that is equivalent to this for my package `@oac/stencil-library`?

Comment: Depends on your build system. If you use Vite, you can use an [URL import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#importing-asset-as-url) in the script (`import src from '...?url'`) and then use the resulting URL in the head script's `src`.

Comment: Yeah, it's using Vite, it's a standard Svelte app. I have the library npm installed. I'm not looking to use the URL. Wondering if there's an equivalent path in the npm package. `@ionic/core/dist/ionic.js` doesn't marry up with anything in my stencil library.

Comment: There is no "standard Svelte app". Whether you can import everything from one entry point depends on your *exports*. You can define a single file as an entry point and export all your components from there to get something like this.

Comment: Standard, as in I ran this `npm create svelte@latest myapp` from the docs. I'm concerned about importing my stencil library in the recommended way. I couldn't find clear information in their docs or after trawling Google search pages. I want to get it right so I can put it in the how-to docs for the component library. No worries anyway, cheers for the help so far.